# Can a speeding citation/conviction prevent receiving a green card?

Tags: usa, greencard

Can a conviction for a speeding offence have an adverse impact on  GC application?

The sentence carries a fine and a 4 points penalty.

Comment: When you say "conviction" what do you mean? Where you arrested or just issued a citation/ticket?

Comment: Issued a ticket

Comment: @Ghaag That is not a conviction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer may heavily depend on the circumstances but in general a speeding ticket won't be an issue according to [instructions to I-485](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-485instr.pdf):

> **NOTE: Unless a traffic insident was alcohol or drug-related, you do not need to submit documentation for traffic fines and incidents that did not involve an actual arrest if the only penalty was a fine of less then $500 and/or points on your driver's license.**

Additionally on the [form itself](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-485.pdf)

> Have you ever been arrested, fined, cited, ...., excluding traffic violations?